# SAS Looping: Summing observations vertically based on conditionally

Tags: loops, sas

I have a dataset that looks like:

Zip Codes     Total Cars

- 11111            *3*
- 11111            *4*
- 23232            *1*
- 44331            *0*
- 44331            *10*
- 18860            *6*
- 18860            *6*
- 18860            *6*
- 18860            *8*

Ther are 3 million+ rows just like this, with varying zips. I need to sum total cars for each zip code, such that the resulting table looks like

Zip Codes     Total Cars

- 11111             *7*
- 23232             *1*
- 44331            *10*
- 18860            *26*
  .
  .
  .

Manually inputting zips into the code is not an option considering the size of the dataset. Thoughts?

Comment: Being new to this, I'd recommend that you look into doing a tutorial on SQL such as this one: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_syntax.asp .  You will then be able to elaborate on the SQL answer that @mjsqu provides below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both answers so far are OK, but here is a more detailed explanation of both possible methods:

**PROC SQL METHOD**

```
PROC SQL;
  CREATE TABLE output_table AS
  SELECT ZipCodes,
  SUM(Total_Cars) as Total_Cars
  FROM input_table
  GROUP BY ZipCodes;
QUIT;
```

The `GROUP BY` clause can also be written `GROUP BY 1`, omitting `ZipCodes`, as this refers to the 1st column in the `SELECT` clause.

**PROC SUMMARY METHOD**

```
PROC SUMMARY DATA=input_table NWAY;
             CLASS ZipCodes;
             VAR Total_Cars;
             OUTPUT OUT=output_table (DROP=_TYPE_ _FREQ_) SUM()=;
RUN;
```

The method is similar to another answer to this question, but I've added:

- `NWAY` - gives only the maximum level of summarisation, here it's not as important because you have only one `CLASS` variable, meaning there is only one level of summarisation. However, without `NWAY` you get an extra row showing the total value of `Total_Cars` across the whole dataset, which is not something you asked for in your question.
- `DROP=_TYPE_ _FREQ_` - This removes the automatic variables:

  - `_TYPE_` - which shows the level of summarisation (see comment above), which would just be a column containing the value `1`.
  - `_FREQ_` - gives a frequency count of the `ZipCodes`, which although useful, isn't something you wanted in your question.

**DATA STEP METHOD**

```
PROC SORT DATA=input_table (RENAME=(Total_Cars = tc)) OUT=_temp;
  BY ZipCodes;
RUN;

DATA output_table (DROP=TC);
  SET _temp;
  BY ZipCodes;
  IF first.ZipCodes THEN Total_Cars = 0;
  Total_Cars+tc;
  IF last.ZipCodes THEN OUTPUT;
RUN;
```

This is just included for completeness, it's not as efficient as it requires pre-sorting.

Answer (score 1):

To supplement @mjsqu's answer, for (more) completeness:

```
data testin;
    input Zip Cars;
    datalines;
11111 3
11111 4
23232 1
44331 0
44331 10
18860 6
18860 6
18860 6
18860 8
;
```

**PROC TABULATE METHOD**

```
proc tabulate data=testin out=testout

    /*drop extra created vars and rename as needed*/
    (drop=_type_ _page_ _table_ rename=(Zip='Zip Codes'n Cars_Sum='Total Cars'n));

    /*grouping variable, also used to sort output in ascending order*/
    class Zip;

    /* variable to be analyzed*/
    var Cars;

    /*sum cars by zip code*/
    table Zip, Cars*(sum);
run;
```

If using Enterprise Guide, this produces a dataset and a results table. To suppress the results and only output a dataset, include this line before "proc tabulate":

```
ods select none; /*suppress ods output*/
```

and this after "run":

```
ods select all; /*restore ods output*/
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The variable upon which you want to sum is "ZipCodes" so that will go into "Class" section.
2. You want to sum Total_cars , so that will go into "var" section.
3. Input_table and Output_table is self explanatory.

/***Code**/

```
   proc summary data=Input_table;
               class ZipCodes;
               var Total_cars;
        output out=Output_table
        sum()=;
        run;
```

Comment: Try to be more specific in your answer and explain better as to what your code snippet is doing

Answer (score 0):

You can use proc sql. this is a very simple step

```
proc sql;

create table new as

select Zipcodes, sum(Total Cars) as total_cars from table_have group by Zipcodes

;
```

quit;

Comment: Can you format the code in your answer by highlighting and pressing Ctrl+K please?

Comment: Hi mjsqu - I have updated the format... Hope it is more understanble now